# MySQL CAST as unsigned doesn't work

Tags: mysql, casting

I created the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
model,
substring_index(group_concat(id ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) AS newid, 
substring_index(group_concat(mainimage ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) AS newmainimage
FROM `example-table`
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY newid DESC;
```

The problem is that this query sorts the variable `newid` like this: 99, 9, 87, 121, 11 while I would like to see: 121, 99, 87, 11, 9.

I thought the answer would be to change `ORDER BY newid DESC` in `ORDER BY CAST(newid AS UNSIGNED) DESC` but this gives me no results at all so apparently I'm wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to use the CAST in ORDER BY _inside_ the GROUP_CONCAT; it is likely that you're storing your id values as strings so they will always use string ordering without such casts.

Comment: Can you share the table schema?

Comment: @Uueerdo Using it inside the GROUP_CONCAT function didn't work, but you helped me on the way. I ended up using the CAST function around the substring_index function and that does the trick: `cast(substring_index(group_concat(id ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) as unsigned) AS newid`

Comment: Oh, I see, I kind of overlooked the substring_index since the "99, 9 ..." looked like group_concat results.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently I should have used the CAST function like this:

```
cast(substring_index(group_concat(id ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) as unsigned) AS newid
```

Comment: ...actually, that is a bit odd; if that works, then your original `ORDER BY CAST(newid AS UNSIGNED) DESC` should have worked as well.

Comment: That's what I assumed too, but as I wrote in the question my original code doesn't put the results in the right order. I still don't have any explanation for it though ...